# I need a RegEx to validate not "NONE"

Tags: regex

I have a text field and am looking to have if be valid for all values other than "NONE" without the quotes. I know a comparison would be easy but the system I am using only validates via RegEx expressions. What would the RegEx expression be for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!NONE$)
```

What this means is find me the starting anchor that *isn't* followed by "NONE' and then terminator. So it should match anything else.